# Chaining Tasks with Faulted checks

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, task, xamarin-studio

I'm using tasks to do a number of web service calls, and want to back out if it fails at any point. Here's my code at the moment:

```
service.Login(usernameTextField.Text, passwordTextField.Text).ContinueWith( t => {
    if (t.IsFaulted){
        new UIAlertView("Login Failed", "Unable to contact server at this time", null, "OK").Show();
    } else {
        if (t.Result)
        {
            service.GetImportantData ().ContinueWith (genericTask => {
                if (genericTask.IsFaulted){
                    new UIAlertView("Login Failed", "Unable to contact server at this time", null, "OK").Show();
                }
                else {
                    service.SyncUserSpecificData().ContinueWith(projectTask => {
                        NavigationController.PopToRootViewController(true);
                    });
                }
            }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext ());

        } else {
            new UIAlertView("Login Failed", "Please check your login and try again", null, "OK").Show();
        }
    }
    loadingOverlay.Hide();

});
```

It's a Xamarin app but that shouldn't matter as I'm just wondering is there a better way to compose them including the error checks as it's callback soup at the moment.

Comment: I take it you can't use C# 5?

Comment: How exactly would you expect the TPL to know what is necessary to "undo" changes made by the tasks that executed successfully?

Comment: @CoryNelson I think Xamarin has async/await if that's what you are after, any chance you could show me an example of how this would improve?

Comment: @M.Babcock no idea what you are talking about. There's no changes to undo, I'm just asking if there's a better way to compose the tasks, perhaps with just 1 IsFaulted check at the end or something? I'm simply trying to learn.

Comment: This is some exceptionally gnarly code with some behavior I'm not sure you wanted. Can you post the code as you would write it if the async bits were synchronous? It will help in cleanly translating it into what you intended.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to go off the idea that your intended flow is this:

```
static void DoSomething()
{
    try
    {
        bool isLoggedIn = service.Login(usernameTextField.Text, passwordTextField.Text);

        if(!isLoggedIn)
        {
            new UIAlertView("Login Failed",
                    "Please check your login and try again", null, "OK").Show();
            return;
        }

        service.GetImportantData();
        service.SyncUserSpecificData();
        NavigationController.PopToRootViewController(true);
    }
    catch
    {
        new UIAlertView("Login Failed",
                "Unable to contact server at this time", null, "OK").Show();
    }
    finally
    {
        loadingOverlay.Hide();
    }
}
```

In which case, I would write it asynchronously like so:

```
static void DoSomething()
{
    service.Login(usernameTextField.Text, passwordTextField.Text)
        .ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            bool isLoggedIn = task.Result;

            if(!isLoggedIn)
            {
                new UIAlertView("Login Failed",
                        "Please check your login and try again", null, "OK").Show();

                // this is just a dummy task to return without error.
                return Task.FromResult(false);
            }

            return service.GetImportantData()
                .ContinueWith(task2 =>
                {
                    // do something with task2
                    task2.Wait(); // just forcing exceptions to be thrown.

                    return service.SyncUserSpecificData();
                }).Unwrap()
                .ContinueWith(task2 =>
                {
                    // task2 is the result from SyncUserSpecificData().
                    task2.Wait(); // again just forcing exceptions to be thrown.

                    NavigationController.PopToRootViewController(true);
                });
        }).Unwrap()
        .ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            new UIAlertView("Login Failed",
                    "Unable to contact server at this time", null, "OK").Show();
        }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted)
        .ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            loadingOverlay.Hide();
        });
}
```

Some big differences here:

First, `Unwrap()` is used to compose a chain of continuations without having a big mess of nested calls. When you return a `Task` from within a continuation, you get a `Task<Task>`, and `Unwrap()` just returns that inner `Task`. It's not a magic bullet but it goes mighty far.

Second, I am letting exceptions get thrown, without manually checking `IsFaulted` at every turn. When you call `Result`, they'll get thrown if they're there.

Third, the exceptions are flowing naturally through the continuations until they enter a single continuation at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin does support the `async/await` keywords and you can even create Portable Class Libraries that support this, as announced in [PCL and .NET NuGet Libraries are now enabled for Xamarin](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/11/13/pcl-and-net-nuget-libraries-are-now-enabled-for-xamarin.aspx).

This means that you can now add Microsoft.Bcl.Async to your project and use `async/await` even in non-MS platforms.

Using `async/await` you can rewrite your code like this:

```
public async Task DoStuffAsync()
{
   try
   {
       var success=await service.Login(usernameTextField.Text, passwordTextField.Text);
       if(success)
       {
           var data=await service.GetImportantData();
           await service.SyncUserSpecificData();
           NavigationController.PopToRootViewController(true);
       }
   }
   catch(WebException exc)
   {
       new UIAlertView("Login Failed", "Unable to contact server at this time", null, "OK").Show();
   }
   catch(Exception exc)
   {
       new UIAlertView("Login Failed", ex.Message, null, "OK").Show();
   }

   loadingOverlay.Hide();
}
```